# python how to traversal a binary search tree using inorder/pre/post/ without recursion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree

In python 3

```
class BinaryTree:
"""
=== Private Attributes ===
@type _root: object | None
@type _left: BinaryTree | None
@type _right: BinaryTree | None

"""
def __init__(self, root, left, right):

    if root is None:
        # store an empty BinaryTree
        self._root = None
        self._left = None
        self._right = None
    else:
        self._root = root
        self._left = left
        self._right = right

def is_empty(self):
    return self._root is None
```

I know how to traverse this binary tree recursively, but I'm wondering how to do it without recursion

Comment: http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stack method to do tree traversal without recursion.
I am giving example for inorder

```
def inOrder(root):

    # Set current to root of binary tree
    current = root 
    s = [] # initialze stack
    done = 0

    while(not done):

        # Reach the left most Node of the current Node
        if current is not None:

            # Place pointer to a tree node on the stack 
            # before traversing the node's left subtree
            s.append(current)

            current = current.left 


        # BackTrack from the empty subtree and visit the Node
        # at the top of the stack; however, if the stack is 
        # empty you are done
        else:
            if(len(s) >0 ):
                current = s.pop()
                print current.data,

                # We have visited the node and its left 
                # subtree. Now, it's right subtree's turn
                current = current.right 

            else:
                done = 1
```

For more explanation you can consider [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xLQKdq0Ffjg&t=755s](http://this) tutorial

Comment: Nice! So does preorder and postorder follows the similar pattern?

Comment: They will also use the stack but with different pattern.You can watch given youtube video to know more for preorder and postorder.